# Issue with Makefile for mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, makefile

I'm having issues linking mysql to my project. I've tried several ways that I found online (I'm new to Makefiles so bear with me) anyway, here's my makefile:

```
CC=g++

CFLAG=-c

INCLUDES="/Library/mysql"

all:myapp
myapp: main.o Application.o
    $(CC) main.o Application.o

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp

Application.o: Application.cpp $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) -lm $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) Application.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o myapp
```

mysql.h is #included in the Application.h file. The mysql folder is located in "/Library"
I'm running OS X Mavericks (if that's relevant).

The error is

```
make: *** No rule to make target `"/Library/mysql"', needed by `Application.o'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the variables `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` for C++ compiler and flags, not `CC` and `CFLAGS`; those are for C compilers.

When you pass directories to the compiler for searching for headers, you have to prefix them with the `-I` flag.  Also preprocessor flags are best put in the `CPPFLAGS` variable, so you should use:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I/Library/mysql
```

You shouldn't put directories as prefixes for targets, so don't add the `$(INCLUDES)` (or `$(CPPFLAGS)`) variable to the prerequisites list of `Application.o`.